# Stored procedure with optional parameters

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a C# application that sends the parameters to the following stored procedure:

```
@Lot nchar (112)= NULL,              

@Oper nchar (112)= NULL

SELECT  [Lot].Lot,

lot.Oper

FROM DB
where (@Lot is null or ( Lot= @Lot)) 
and (@Oper is null or ( Oper= @Oper))
```

I cannot get any results if I leave fields blank in my application.

Comment: Side note: I would recommend **NOT** to use `(N)CHAR(n)` for anything much longer than maybe 3, 5 characters. `(N)CHAR(n)` will **always** fill up the defined - 112 characters or 224 bytes in your case - even if you want to store only `A` in your string. For anything beyond 5 characters, I'd recommend using the **variable length** string types - `VARCHAR(n) / NVARCHAR(n)` for better performance and less wasted space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that your application's definitely of a "blank" field is going to be an empty string.  Most likely, your code is taking that blank string and passing that as the parameters to your stored procedure.  Therefore your defaults (of `NULL`) are not used, but instead `@Lot` and/or `@Oper` have the value of `''`.

If that's the case, your `SELECT` query is effectively:

```
select ...
from DB
where Lot = ''
and Oper = '';
```

Check for blank strings before passing parameter values, and if that's the case then just don't pass those parameters to the stored procedure.  Or handle that in the backend (that wouldn't be my first option, but it's still an option).

Comment: Thanks that worked i switched it to '' and got the expected results. I spent 1/2 a day looking at this :-)

Comment: No problem, glad to help.  It's a common mistake :-)